# Datatables accessing ajax data issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Hi I am trying to implement the datatables example and got blocked while accessing sample data.

[Here is the fiddle where I got blocked](http://jsfiddle.net/chandrashekarthota/Tg64e/)

[Here is data tables working example from site](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            {
                "class":          'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
```

Comment: do you haVE ANY DATA inside ../ajax/data/objects.txt ??

Comment: instead of .txt file I want to access mock data.

Comment: first chose which datasource approprite for you

Answer (score 2):

You are using ajax data source from a text file and again want's to show data from javascript source. then you have to try like https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html
as sakir suggested there are four data sources for data table. use any of them as per your requirement

```
//see here
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html
```

Answer (score 0):

the link you have gave,there are different datasource types

some o them like this.

```
Data sources

    HTML (DOM) sourced data
    Ajax sourced data
    Javascript sourced data
    Server-side processing
```

I guess you need to use `Javascript sourced data` to run your example properlly as you desribe it as a javascript data